# When I try to save to ui colors with userDefaults, Xcode gives me the error : Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift, debugging, colors, userdefaults

I am trying to allow my app to save UIColors in settings, and when I tried to save the settings for the background color it worked. But when I add a second block of code that should allow me to save a second UIColor, it gives me the error - Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value. Can someone show me how to save the second UIColor without an error?

```
      // First UIColor save - Works
    var dd = UIColor(hex: UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "TheMainUIColour") as! String )

    UserDefaults.standard.set(dd.toHexString, forKey: "TheMainUIColour")

    let  mainBackgroundColour = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "TheMainUIColour") as! String

    let color = UIColor(hex: mainBackgroundColour)

    self.view.backgroundColor = dd

    // Second UIColor Save - Doesnt Work
    let dd2: UIColor = UIColor(hex: UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "TheMainUIColour2") as! String )
    UserDefaults.standard.set(dd2, forKey: "TheMainUIColour2")

    let  mainBackgroundColour2 = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "TheMainUIColour2") as! String

    let color2 = UIColor(hex: mainBackgroundColour2)
```

Comment: Do not use `value(forKey:)`. Use `string(forKey:)` or `object(forKey:)` or any of the other documented methods in `UserDefaults`. But do not use `value(forKey:)` or `setValue(_:forKey:)`.

Comment: change `UserDefaults.standard.set(dd2, forKey: "TheMainUIColour2")` to `UserDefaults.standard.set(dd2. toHexString, forKey: "TheMainUIColour2")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is

```
   var dd2:UIColor = UIColor(hex: UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "TheMainUIColour2") as! String )
```

it reads from defaults not save , don't use ! to read from defaults as the stored value may be nil , jsut use if let to check the existence of it in defaults or not , if exists use it , if not save the value you want , wjen you open the app again it will read that stored value

```
   if let saved = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "TheMainUIColour2") 
   {
       var dd = UIColor(hex:saved)
   }
   else
   {
        print("No saved color")

        let dd = UIColor.red

        UserDefaults.standard.set(dd.toHexString, forKey: "TheMainUIColour2")

   }
```

Comment: where do I add that?

Comment: Do not use `value(forKey:)`.

Comment: Actually, both blocks need to be fixed.

Comment: he says the crash happens in second, but it's true he should take care of both as they are similar

Comment: The first will crash too on a fresh install of the app.

Comment: @user9405647 use the answer for both colors , the idea is to check with if let whether the value you read from defaults is nil or not whatever the content is

Answer (score 0):

Your code crashes because there is nothing set for the key `TheMainUIColour2` but you then force-unwrap that `nil` value and your app crashes.

Your code also makes little sense as written. You (attempt to) load the current value and create a color from it. You then needlessly write that value back to user defaults. Then you read the value again as a string. And then you create the color from the string again.

Don't do all of those needless extra steps. Load the color if it exists and that is it. This code should not be setting anything. You must have other code that decides on what color to use. That code should save the color to user defaults.

```
if let hexColor = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "TheMainUIColour2") {
    let color2 = UIColor(hex: hexColor)
    // do something with the color
}
```